# How to use Oauth verification method as common function in GoogleCloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, google-cloud-functions

I have many GCP functions and all functions have common function for Oauth verification method.

I have two ways :

1. Add Oauth verification method to all functions.
2. Created separate method oAuthVerification and communicate between functions. (In this case, If user is making one call to GCF but that function again make one more intern call to oAuthVerification . i.e 1 request  == 2 GCF calls .

Can any one suggest me which is best approach or  Is there any another solutions ?

Thanks and Regards,
Tapas

Comment: What is the purpose of your Oauth verification method? To validate the Bearer token? Against which IdP? Or is it for extracting claims from the token?

Comment: Hi @guillaumeblaquiere , I am verifying my token against oauth0 server.

Answer (score 1):

The way to do the authentication is you may have an API gateway in front of your cloud functions, you can build your API gateway using Cloud Endpoints. for good references please refer to [this](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/get-started-cloud-functions) document.

Comment: Hi , But If i create Open API (Gateway) does it chargeable ?

Comment: Yes it is because it is running on app engine - charge would be as pay for usage

Comment: But keeping my verification method along with my function is better option i feel. Because i don't want to get charged for apigateway . because i have only two functions as of now . future if i get more functions i can plan for gateway.    Thank you @nifCody.   But Keeping Oauth verification method along with functions , does it make any difference or effect on functions ?

Comment: If it is two fiction you can right a common module and duplicate it to those fictions is the better way for less functions